# iOS Label Shadowing

Tags: ios, format, shadow

I have this code here,

```
label.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor orangeColor].CGColor;
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,1);
label.layer.shadowRadius = 3.0;
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
label.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:label.frame cornerRadius:20]CGPath];
```

I am using orange for testing purposes. Why is this not appearing as a shadow? All I am seeing is this, http://img12.imageshack.us/img12/1568/screenshot20130312at415.png

I am trying to get the gray label on the inside to have a shadow around the edges... Any help?

-Henry

Comment: Not sure, may be try bezierPathWithRoundedRect:label.bounds

Comment: @George Nothing... Thanks. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `label.bounds`, not `label.frame`, to create the path.  Also, make sure `label.clipsToBounds` is `NO`.

Comment: When I do, http://pastebin.com/ENGpRfq6

It does add the shadow, but it removes the rounded corners.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `shadowOffset` -1

```
label.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
label.layer.shadowRadius =2.0;
label.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
label.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.01,-1.0);
```

Also set `label.bounds` instead of `label.frame`

```
label.layer.shadowPath = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:label.bounds cornerRadius:20]CGPath];
```

Comment: Weird... And it keeps the rounded corners?

Comment: Shadow with color has appeared right, I am not by computer now , I didn't notice radius but I can have a look once I  am by computer

Comment: Even shadow color not appearing for you?

Comment: @HenryHarris I have tested the code in my app and it shows the rounded corners for the radius as well, you must be having some other issue, you should break down your code into smaller steps. if you create a new project and add label to a the interface and use this code it will work!